# why is my hair not combing at the root! I've tried everything trust me, new too geo nodes

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image][image][image] I'm new too geo nodes and I've tried looking up as far as I can went down the rabbit hole and nothing, please just kindly help i really appreciate anybody that's able and willing, so i made this cap mesh were i will adding hairs on the hair curb sculpt mode right? well i did but no matter what way i make them or move around the curb settings in active tools and workspace settings window, nothing changes i have a geo node that resampled the hair to 30 dots or nodes but for some reason the comb will not comb the root only the rest of the hair, please put mew out of my misery. ill provide as many important photos as i can and ask away lets solve this im done.[[image: example of how hair is not affected at the root][1]]

Comment: its a fukking bug switched to 3.3 and everything worked fine, the switched back to 3.5 and no blenders crazy asss decided to behave itself, lets see how log that last's. just incase anybody run's into the issue, and thanks to anybody that helped, lol me basically.